# Redactor Rails Adding unwanted html tags span style background color

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redactor

I using Using gem redactor-rails 0.5.0 with Rails 3.2.17

When I type in:

[image]

And then hit `</>` button on top right corner of the editor:

I get the following:

```
<p>
    Some Dummy Text<span style="background-color: initial;"></span>
</p>
```

Is there a way to configure this on redactor to not add the span on its own?

Comment: There might be a way to hide the `</>` button in this WYSIWYG editor

Comment: Pressing on `</>` is not causing the unwanted spans to be added, its added automatically when the text is entered.

Comment: Is it only added at the end? Also googling : `"background-color: initial" redactor` gave a result from mid 2014 that seemed similar.

Comment: its added to the beginning if the text is longer, found this to be relate: http://support.statamic.com/discussions/general-questions-best-practices/16796-unwanted-html-when-convert-text-to-list-in-redactor but no solution

Comment: @neo did you find any solution for this? I am also facing same issue.